# Maximo Anywhere 7.6 - Standard apps getting stuck

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I had setup Maximo Anywhere 7.6 in our landscape to test the standard apps provided by IBM.

I had tested couple of apps successfully but have some or the other issue with the other apps. The issues are more or less with the apps becoming hung at a screen.

Issues And Returns App -> When opened the Storeroom list to select a store room, the app is stuck at the screen. I'm unable to select a value and also not able to return to the home screen.

Inspection -> When an update is made on the Workorder (Like adding a Worklog or status change etc), the app stucks showing the Loading icon. It doesn't respond at all.

I have similar issues when testing the Transfers app, Physical Count app as well.

Anyone encountered similar issues? If yes, is there any resolution available?

Device Used: ASUS Nexus 7 (2013)
Apps built for API Level 19
Tablet OS: Android Lollipop

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

We know about the Inspection app hang on status change and have an IFix available but the others are new to me. Can you please open a PMR with our support team to track?

Comment: Hi Scott,Thanks for your response. I'll raise a PMR about the other apps. Could you please let us know the process to download the iFix for Inspection app? Also could you please let me know if there is any process to debug the app in eclipse or monitoring the app in logcat?

Comment: Hi Scott, We did try to find out the iFix for inpection app in the Fix Central. We were unable to find any iFix for v7.6. There are fixes available for all the previous versions but not for 7.6 Could you please let me know if I'm not on right path? URL is https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral

Comment: That's the right place, but we only publish iFixes currently on request.  I recommend that you debug in Chrome simulator, and make sure you expand developer tools and click break on exceptions.  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#pause-on-exceptions

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for your suggestion. With the help of the link provided, I have debugged Issues & Returns App. When we select a storeroom in the list, the value is not being populated back the list stays there. Error in the console is "Cannot read property 'lookupAttribute' of undefined". This is being returned in LookupHandler.js at line 42 due to returnObject is coming as undefined. Is something wrong in the app.xml where the selected data is not captured and error is returned? Can you please help us on this.